# Translate Nginx conf in Apache Htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx, http-accept-language

I have to change a mobile application data folder from Nginx to Apache server so I will have to use a Htaccess file instead of nginx config. I cannot translate this Nginx configuration :

```
location ~ ^/mobile/(.*)$ {
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
         add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS";
         add_header Vary "Accept-Language";
         root /var/www/app/mobile/;
         try_files /$http_accept_language/$1 /nolang/$1 =404;
    }
```

The document root on the new server is `/prod/var/www/html/mobile`

Any help?

Comment: What is the document root of your site? (Is there a "desktop" version? If so, how is this handled?)

Comment: I edited the question with more details